# Susy getting footer at bottom

Tags: css, footer, sticky, susy-compass

Using Susy Grids, how do you force the container to be min-height 100% and footer to be at the bottom of the page.

html

```
<div class="page">
  <header id="header-container">header</header>
  <section ="main-container">
    some short content
  </section>
  <footer id="footer-container">footer</footer>
</div>
```

css/scss

```
$total-columns  : 16; 
$column-width   : 4.5%;
$gutter-width   : 1%;
$grid-padding   : 6.5%;
$legacy-support-for-ie6 : false;

.page { @include container;}
#main-container{@include span-columns($total-columns omega);}
#footer-container{
    @include clearfix;
    @include reset-columns; 
    min-height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a job for the [Compass Sticky Footer mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/).

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong - but susy usually deals with width or horizontal based positioning problems (the Y of x-y positioning) - height and vertical positioning is not something susy worries about.

Again, I might be wrong - but I think you're looking to the wrong tool for this - Plus, you can always just write *normal* css to achieve what you're trying to do.

Tools like this are great, but it's a good thing to keep in mind that in the end you're really just getting CSS - so if you're not sure how to use CSS to accomplish something maybe you shouldn't be using tools to write that CSS for you.  I always make sure the tools I'm using produces the CSS that I want it to, if it's not - I don't use that tool.